# How to measure CPU usage on BenchmarkDotNet?

Tags: c#, memory-management, benchmarkdotnet

I am using DotNet Benchmark and I can get the memory usage information as in the table below. But I need to access how much **CPU usage** is in the process I have done. Does DotNetBenchmark have this feature? If not, what method should I use?

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Get10000Records | 38.70 ms | 1.413 ms | 4.165 ms | 2000.0000 | 1000.0000 | - | 12 MB |
| Get100000Records | 558.30 ms | 11.157 ms | 22.024 ms | 19000.0000 | 6000.0000 | 2000.0000 | 121 MB |

Comment: You can try looking into [hardware counters](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/configs/diagnosers.html#sample-introhardwarecounters) on windows (requires `BenchmarkDotNet.Diagnostics.Windows` nuget)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this as well and ended up implementing my own `CpuDiagnoser` to do so.
Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/MarkPflug/55173728458020c6d335cc099c891c0b). It requires that your benchmarks are run in-process, and I suspect the timings aren't reliable enough unless your benchmarks run for at least tens of milliseconds.

Copy this file into your benchmark project, add `[CpuDiagnoser]` to a benchmark class and it will output CPU usage for user and priviledged time. The tests need to be run InProc for this to work, however.